# Debian Bullseye - dependency problems

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

After an upgrade on Debian Bullseye, I got this error :

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-ldb
 apt-listchanges
 lsb-release
 python3-mediainfodll
 caja-mediainfo
 python3-distro
 python3-talloc:amd64
 python3-apt
 python3-debconf
 samba-libs:amd64
 yelp
 libsmbclient:amd64
 mate-user-guide
 gvfs-backends
```

With this message for each package :

```
dpkg: error processing package [PACKAGE NAME] (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Tried to reconfigure but the same errors showed up :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Tried also to reinstall and got this error :

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3 --fix-broken

E: Internal Error, No file name for python3:amd64
```

Comment: Are you using additional apt sources besides the ones Debian is providing?

Comment: I believe paladin is referring to [the Dead Snakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python3` package file in your `apt` cache seems to be corrupted; run

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt reinstall python3
```

to force a re-download. If that still fails, download the package file manually and install it:

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3_3.9.2-3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python3_3.9.2-3_amd64.deb
```

Then try to continue the upgrade:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

Comment: Why would doing it manually change anything, Stephen? If you download the exact same package and install it with the exact same tool (dpkg) as the `apt` command would use, how could doing it manually result in anything different?

Comment: It might make a difference if the `apt` indexes are messed up somehow, or if `apt` itself can’t download the package properly for some reason; the manual approach bypasses `apt` completely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution yesterday, which seemed to fix my package dependencies. And today, some applications started to bugged. After a restart, my Debian is not booting anymore (stop on black screen with only an underscore blinking). I noticed that I have some lib issues (libcurl-gnutls.so.4 and libunwind.so.8). And I think I need to get ride of Wayland and replace by Xorg.